# Write shapefile from list in R

Tags: r, shapefile, st

I have imported a shapefile in R using

`myshape<-st_read("myshapefile.shp")`

This generated a list with 2 variables by n observations: DN and geometry. I've then performed some zonal statistics with [exact_extract](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactextractr/index.html) by running

`extrdata<-exact_extract(myraster,myshape,c('min','max','count','mean','stdev','variety'))`

which generated another list of 6 variables by n observations. I've then merged the two using

`myshape2<-append(myshape,extrdata)`

Thus generating a list of 8 variables by n observations. The list still includes the "geometry" variable of the original list with all the imported multipolygons.

I've thought it would be straightforward to write this latest list back to shapefile using

`st_write(myshape2,"myshape2.shp")`

But, instead, this generate the error

`no applicable method for 'st_write' applied to an object of class "list"`

How can I convert this list back to a shapefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
myshape2<-append(myshape,extrdata)
```

doesn't do a "merge". The function `merge` does a database merge based on matching a column value, but since your extracted data and your polygons are in the same order you can use `cbind` to add ("bind") the columns to your polygon spatial data frame. Here's an example:

```
> cbind(myshape, extrdata)
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 7 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2 ymin: 0 xmax: 8 ymax: 9
CRS:           NA
  DN min max count     mean     stdev variety                       geometry
1  1  50  78   2.0 63.83333  7.903937       7 POLYGON ((6 1, 8 4, 4 0, 6 1))
2  2  25  65  13.5 43.16667 10.106379      23 POLYGON ((2 2, 7 6, 4 9, 2 2))
```

So you can do:

```
myshape2<-cbind(myshape,extrdata)
st_write(myshape2 , "/tmp/out.shp")
```